# Find path in a dict of edges, python

Tags: python, path-finding

I have a dict, printing it looks in this shape:
{(2, 2): (47, 42),
 (2, 37): (21, 116),
 (3, 159): (60, 189),
 .....................
 (483, 284): (451, 297)}
So I have key value where key---->value is an edge.
I want to be able to build a function that finds a path between 2 points, if there is one, and returns only it (assuming there are many paths in the dict).
So I tried doing something like this:
paths variable is my dict, begin and end are 2 dimention int tuples

```
def findPath(paths, begin, end):
    cur = begin
    found = False
    path = [begin]
    while not found:
        if cur == end:
            path.append(end)
            found = True
        else:
            #I don't want to go on blind like this: cur = paths[cur]
            # because it may not lead to the end point
    return path
```

More information - there are no circles in the paths dict

How can I implement this? does it need to use recursion?

Comment: You want [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm).

Comment: Dijkstra gave me those paths :( I am trying to retrieve the specific path from the result Dijkstra gave me, which was all paths from begin point to every point

Comment: I got the Dijkstra implementation here: https://gist.github.com/econchick/4666413

Comment: You keep track of parent node for each node in a dictionary, so you can reconstruct the path later.

Comment: See `P` in http://code.activestate.com/recipes/119466-dijkstras-algorithm-for-shortest-paths/ for example.

Comment: Checking it out, thanks